# Use same credentials in GNOME Files and SSH

Tags: ssh, openssh, nautilus, gnome-keyring

With GNOME Files, I use a password to access a CIFS (Samba) share. For the remainder of the session, GNOME maintains my credentials and I don't have to enter the password again, even after suspending and resuming my client machine.

I also connect with the same user to an SSH session on the same server with OpenSSH. Yet, for every connection (like after a suspend and resume), I have to enter the password. Can I associate the CIFS login with the SSH login somehow?

If not, can I use GNOME Keyring to remember the password of the SSH session? I see that `$SSH_AUTh_SOCK` is pointing to `/run/user/$UID/keyring/ssh`, but `ssh` still always asks for a password.

Comment: `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` will point to the socket for public key authentication, not password authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The question still stands, then, about how to use the GNOME Keyring with SSH password authentication or to share authentication between GNOME Files and SSH.